# Mysqli_query to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new in prepared statement and is this the correct sequence using procedural?

```
$stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT user_id,username, password, user_type FROM user WHERE username=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $user, $password, $user_type);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

if($someCond){
   mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
   mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: What's the output? Are you getting any error?

Comment: im still confuse about mysqli_Stmt_store_result and mysqli_stmt_free_result, it is important in every statement?